# showing real-time web statistics - hits from visitors

Tags: php, ajax

I have a web statistic website based on php script. I want to show in real-time to my clients when a visitors hits their website. The info is presented in static way, the clients must refresh the page to see if any hit ocurred. I searched and tried...but nothing.

Answer (score 2):

use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

demo:

```
setInterval(function(){
      $("#statistics").load("statistics.php");
}, 10000);
```

Comment: "Hello doctor. I'm sick. Heal me please. Thanks". You should add some more information about what is "not working"